# Impossible to change the value of "Build list using" for the second time

Tags: list, adobe, components, aem

I create a site using CMS Adobe Day CQ5. I use on the  page component "list" and found a bug. Impossible to change the value of "Build list using" for the second time. Steps to reproduce:

1. Add "list" to the page
2. Right click on component -> Edit -> Set the following parameters:
   Build list using = Child pages
3. Select the parent page
4. Click OK (parameters are saved, list is displayed at the page)
5. Right click on component -> Edit -> Try to set:  Build list using = Fixed list

Result: It is impossible to change the value of Build list using for the second time. I have not found a solution to this problem at Adobe site an on the internet:( Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem, and it was quite simple. You need to add to component's node the child node with property "jsr:prinaryType" = "cq:EditConfig", and add to this node a chold node too. This last node have properties "jcr:primaryType" = "cq:EditListenersConfig" and "afteredit" = "REFRESH_PAGE". This will allow automatically reload page after every editing component through his dialogue.

Finally, folder of your component should just have a XML-file "_cq_editConfig.xml" with the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    ....
    <cq:listeners jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig" afteredit="REFRESH_PAGE"/>
    ....
</jcr:root>
```